# running Strawberry Perl in Windows 8 PowerShell ISE

Tags: perl, powershell, windows-8

I am trying to run multiple Perl commands from the command line in PowerShell in Windows 8.

This works

```
perl -e "print 'Joe'";
```

This prints:

```
Joe
```

This does not work

```
perl -e "my $string = 'Joe'; print $string;"
```

This gives me an error

```
perl : syntax error at -e line 1, near "my  ="
At line:1 char:1
+ perl -e "my $string = 'Joe'; print $string;"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (syntax error at -e line 1, near "my  =":String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Can someone point out the obvious mistake I am missing? Thanks. I usually do this on UNIX but use back ticks. as a wrapper instead of double quotes.

Comment: I don't know PowerShell, but it looks like the variable `$string` was interpolated into the `-e` code *before* it was passed as an argument to Perl → change the delimiter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this, but I can't test it

```
perl -e 'my $string = ''Joe''; print $string;'
```

In powershell `$string` is a variable, and in double quotes variable are expanded with the value assigned. In single quotes are take as literal.
To escape `'` in single quotes redouble it as `''`

or try:

```
perl -e  "my `$string = 'Joe'; print `$string;"
```

the ` is the escape character in powershell.